# Output shows myArray.split is not a function and not working properly

Tags: javascript

1.shows split is not a function.

```js
let myArray = ["Ryu", "Ken", "Chun-Li", "Cammy", "Guile",
  "Sakura", "Sagat", "Juri"];
myArray.pop()
myArray.push("sad", "jan")

let splt = myArray.split(",");
```

Comment: `split()` is used to turn split a string into an array. You already have an array, why do you need to split it?

Comment: What are you expecting the result to be?

Comment: Because there is no split method for array. myArray is already an array object. :)